# Not seeing full data in the string buffer in mutli thread logging

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, stringbuffer

I am using ThreadLocal StringBuffer for storing entire log to move it to kibana at the end of each test case execution. But when I am running cases in parallel, the log is loosing some entries.
I am writing the log into file before adding it to StringBuffer and I see all entires in the log file but not in the StringBuffer.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

I tried String Builder but no luck. Tried to make synchronized still no luck. I tried writing the log entry into file before moving into string buffer and I see all entire there but not getting all entries in string buffer

```
public abstract class Messages {

    static ThreadLocal<StringBuffer> msg;
    public static void init() {
         msg = new ThreadLocal<StringBuffer>() {
            @Override
            protected StringBuffer initialValue() {
                return new StringBuffer();
            }
     };

     public static void addMsg(String msg) {
          msg.get().append(msg + "\r\n");
            System.out.println(msg);
    }
}

public class CallingClass(){
    public void callingMethod(String threadName){
       Messages.init();
       Messages.addMsg("Hi");
       Messages.addMsg("This");
       Messages.addMsg("Is");
       Messages.addMsg("Testing");
       Messages.addMsg("For");
       Messages.addMsg("Multi");
       Messages.addMsg("Thread");
       Messages.addMsg("UI");
       Messages.addMsg(threadName + "!!");
    }
}
```

From my cucumber tests, we call the above method callingMethod from each thread.

I am running 10 parallel threads and the result is different when I print the msg at the end from all 10 threads, I see for some threads it is missing the first few entries.

I tried making addMsg synchronized but still no luck. In a single thread execution, the log is proper and also when I am using debug from eclipse, the log is coming properly as expected.

Comment: Is it reproducible? Can you provide some code of your tests - or similiar tests - so we can have a look. `StringBuilder` is not thread safe, while `StringBuffer` is. How do you find out, when all test cases are ready and you can send data? Maybe that synchronization is not done properly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple threads call `Messages.init()`.

The first time we call `init` the previous value of `null` for `msg` is replaced with a new `ThreadLocal`.

The next time we call `init` the previous value is replaced *with a new copy of `ThreadLocal`*, effectively discarding all previously used/created `StringBuffer` objects.

And the same the next time ...

There's no point in that `init` method and you should get rid of it (and all calls to it) and just define `msg` like this:

```
static final ThreadLocal<StringBuffer> msg = new ThreadLocal<StringBuffer>() {
            @Override
            protected StringBuffer initialValue() {
                return new StringBuffer();
            }
     };
```

The whole point of `ThreadLocal` is that you only need **one instance** of it to give *each thread their own `StringBuffer`*.

Also, if all access to the content is via those methods, then the synchronization/thread safety of `StringBuffer` isn't needed and you should use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: After making it final the logs are getting populated properly. Thanks for the help.